# Changing content of a webpage using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Is it possible to change the content of a webpage using ajax?
My need is to actually change the options of a selection. 
For example my `x123.com/setting.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Webpage</title> 
    <script>
    function save_changes() {
        //save the selection
    }
    </script>

</head>            
<body>
    <select name="" multiple>
        <option value="123">123</option>
        <option value="456">456</option>
    </select>                           
    <input type="button" name="Submit Dude" onclick='save_changes()'>
</body>                                 
</html>
```

I want to give a request from `x123.com/123.html` and reload the current page(`x123.com/123.html`) so that the changes in `x123.com/setting.html` are actually reflected in this one.

Lemme know if my explanation is not clear.

Comment: Check the following links www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost.shtml

Comment: I have a blog post that shows how to do that... http://events.manzwebdesigns.com/?p=111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax this way with  jquery

include the jquery script

[Making the call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

also the form needs to have a proper format so you can use the [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method

```
<form action="" method="">
   <select name="selection" multiple>
     <option value="123">123</option>
     <option value="456">456</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @lbu, when i click some from from `x123.com/123.html` it should automatically change the selection in `x123.com/setting.html` and save those changes (in the background) and then reload the current page.

Comment: i think what you are looking for is server-side coding. it can be done in javascript but for saving you will need server-side depending on the OS you are using, i recommend getting started with php. for windows machines, there is [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com), LINUX there is [LAMP](http://www.sph.umich.edu/csg/abecasis/LAMP/download/) and mac there is [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html) for a good php tutorial [Check this link](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627-PHP-101-PHP-For-the-Absolute-Beginner)

Comment: Hi @lbu, I think you got it wrong, So basically i'm developing a chrome extension, which performs all the actions on the client end only. The ajax posting should be performed in the extensions background.html. Running some javascript functions on the `x123.com/setting.html` from the background while you are on the `x123.com/123.html`. And making the current page reload.

Comment: Did you take a look at link i provided in my answer?